# How does PostgreSQL order textual values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

The following query

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('c'), ('a'), ('b'), ('"a"')) X ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

produces

```
a
"a"
b
c
```

So how come does `"a"` appear after `a` even though it starts with a non alphabetic character (ie `"`) ?

I thought the output should be

```
"a"
a
b
c
```

It seems like PostgreSQL is stripping non alphabetic characters while sorting those values but that does't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort behaviour of text (char, varchar, text) depends on the *current collation of your locale*. Try using,

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES('c'), ('a'), ('b'), ('"a"')) X(col) 
ORDER BY col COLLATE "C" asc;
```

The "C" collation is a **byte-wise collation** that ignores national language rules, encoding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is something "funny" going on with the collation of the literal in the VALUES row value constructor, but if you use a "real" table, your query sorts as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE T (StringCol VARCHAR(5));
INSERT T Values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('"a"');
SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY 1
```

I took a quick look at [this topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/collation.html), but couldn't find an obvious reason, a more thorough read is needed, but you should find your answer there.

HTH